# Adding 2 css in a single element using jquery mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The top size will be dynamic so I should initialize this on the jquery and not on the default css style. Do anyone know how to do this?

`

```js
$('.box').hover(function(){
  /*I need to inialize the $top size here before proceeding to the below css*/
  $('.hover',this).css({'top':'0'});
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hover  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_zAA8810ONGbOaB_F5hZ1prrTnC749ko6otAfyltJBSCKPgIm" alt="img">
    <div class="hover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Javascript.

```css
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 10% auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
    display:block;
    top:0%;
}

.box:hover .content {
    top:-100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Enter Leave Over Out</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I edited my question code snippet. so from your point box shouldn't be initialized to 0 this will be done on jquery

Comment: @Krishna That confused me. What is now the purpose of your code?

Comment: This is for the hover box based on the direction where the mouse is coming from. so say example the mouse was from the bottom the top size should be top:-100% and from there it will animate to top: 0

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the jQuery code, the `mouseenter` is not closed properly. Change it into the following:

```
$(".box").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.hover', this).css({'display': 'block'});
    $('.hover', this).css({'top': '100%'});
    $('.hover', this).css({'top': '0'});
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.hover', this).css({'top': '-100%'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi I need to intialize the top size on the jquery not on the css it self because this will be dynamic. I had already change my code snippet and question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do by first setting top to 100%, then to 0? 0 will override the previous settings (100%). You also have a missing closing bracket ( '}' ) after the mouseenter function. 

**CSS Only Solution**

Do I correctly assume that you want a colored overlay on top of the .box on hover? You can do it with pure css, easy example is available on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slidetop) and here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goe3y5wn/2/) created from your example. I just switched hover class to overlay to avoid confusion.

```
.box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   margin: 10% auto;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.box:hover .overlay{
  top:0;
  height:100%;
}
```

The `.box:hover .overlay` rule is the key - it means it gives this style to the div with overlay class when you hover over it's container - the .box div.

Comment: Hi I need to intialize the top size on the jquery not on the css it self because this will be dynamic. I had already change my code snippet and question.